# SSRS parameter help needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am creating a report in SSRS using T-SQl.
Scenario: I have 3 columns

```
- time_a 
- time_b 
- Delta
```

Delta shows the difference between (time_a - time_b)

so delta has negative as well as positive values. I need to create a parameter in SSRS so users can choose to see either positive or negative or both the values.

```
select 
 case
  when (time_a - time_b) > 0
   then 'positive'
  when (time_a - time_b) < 0
   then 'negative'
 end as differ
from time_entry
```

where I am stuck here that how to create  a parameter in SSRS. (like ??? in @differ)

Answer (score 1):

Set up your `@Delta` parameter:

```
-1   Negative
0    All
1    Positive
```

Find the difference and select on that depending on difference you want:

```
SELECT time_a - time_b AS Delta
FROM time_entry
WHERE ((@Delta = 0) 
OR ((@Delta < 0) AND (time_a - time_b < 0))
OR ((@Delta > 0) AND (time_a - time_b > 0))
```

Comment: Thanks this works but have a question.I set the parameter -1   Negative and  1    Positive but I want I can select negative and positive together without setting values of 0 ALL. Basically I just want to show parameter in SSRS as Negative , Positive or select ALL.So when I do Select All it gives me error "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','."

Comment: It looks like you setting the ALL as the parameter value in the SSRS parameter.  Make sure that your values are -1,0,1.  And the label for the parameter is "Negative", "ALL" , "Positive" respectivley